# How to compare adjacent objects in a List using stream in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, java-stream

Use Case: Iterate a List of sorted objects and consolidate their properties in a Map.

Reference Code:

```
Map<Character, Integer> getEncodedString(List<Character> al) {
    int len = al.size();
    Map<Character, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
    int f = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if(al.get(i) == al.get(i - 1)) {
            f++;
        }
        else {
            m.put(al.get(i - 1), f);
            f = 1;
        }
    }
    if(al.get(len - 2) == al.get(len - 1)) m.put(al.get(len - 1), f + 1);
    else m.put(al.get(len - 1), 1);
    return m;
}
```

I am trying to achieve these results with the help of streams.

Comment: No, if you observe my use case is focused on comparing the objects which cannot be broken down to the indexed data structures. Moreover I am trying to extend it further on complex user defined objects with several properties comparison so unfortunately this does not help.

Comment: Your problem *is* already broken down to an indexed data structure, as that’s what a `List` is. You are even using an indexed based list, `for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)`